# Keyboard with Bottom Tab Bar Menu

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am relatively new to programming in SwiftUI and making User Interfaces. I was able to create this UI through some youtube videos and blog posts. However, I am still having a hard time in getting the tab bar menu at the bottom to "disappear" in a sense when I click on the UITextField. How exactly would I implement this "disappearing" feature inside the current UI via code? Or do I need to design another more efficient menu for my use case? If I need to/would be better if I designed a new UI, can you provide a blog post and/or youtube video that could help in that regard? Here are the images of what my issue currently looks like:

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Below are my swift files:

```swift
//ChatView.swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

struct ChatView: View {
    
    @State var message = ""
    //StateObject is the owner of the object...
    @StateObject var allMessages = Messages()
    
    //@StateObject private var keyboardHandler = KeyboardHandler()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            VStack{
                
                ZStack{
                    
                    /*
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                    }*/
                    
                    VStack(spacing:5){
                        Text("Chat")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .padding(.all)
                
                //Spacer()
                VStack{
                    
                    //Spacer()
                    //Displaying Message...
                    
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                        
                        ScrollViewReader{reader in
                            
                            VStack(spacing: 20){
                                
                                ForEach(allMessages.messages){msg in
                                    
                                    //Chat Bubbles...
                                    
                                    ChatBubble(msg: msg)
                                
                                    
                                }
                                //whenever new data is inserted, scroll to bottom...
                                .onChange(of: allMessages.messages) {(value) in
                                    
                                    //scrolling only user message...
                                    
                                    if value.last!.myMsg{
                                        reader.scrollTo(value.last?.id)
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            .padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
                            .padding(.top, 25)
                            
                        }
                    })
                    
                    HStack(spacing:15){
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 15){
                            TextField("Message", text: self.$message)
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 12)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .background(Color.black
                                        .opacity(0.06)
                                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                        )
                        //.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
                        //.clipShape(Capsule())
                        
                        //send button
                        //hiding view...
                        if message != ""{
                            Button(action: {
                                
                                //appending message...
                                
                                //adding animation...
                                withAnimation(.easeIn){
                                    allMessages.messages.append(Message(id: Date(), message: message, myMsg: true))
                                }
                                
                                message = ""
                                
                            }, label: {
                                
                                Image("send")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 45))
                                    .padding()
                                    //.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                    //.font(.system(size: 0.5))
                                    //.padding(.all)
                                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.07))
                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .animation(.easeOut)
                    //
                }
                .padding(.bottom, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                .background(Color.white)
                //.clipShape(RoundedShape())
                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                .keyboardType(.default)
                //.padding(.bottom, keyboardHandler.keyboardHeight)
                
            }
            //.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .background(Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
        }
    }
}

//Chat Bubbles...

struct ChatBubble : View {
    
    var msg : Message
    var body: some View{
        
        //Automatics scroll to bottom...
        //First assigning id to each row
        
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10){
            
            if msg.myMsg{
                
                //pushing msg to the left...
                
                //minimum space ...
                Spacer(minLength: 25)
                
                Text(msg.message)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.06))
                    //.cornerRadius(15)
                    .clipShape(BubbleArrow(myMsg: msg.myMsg))
            } else {
                
                //pushing msg to the right...
                
                Text(msg.message)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.all)
                    //.background(Color.black.opacity(0.06))
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .clipShape(BubbleArrow(myMsg: msg.myMsg))
                
                Spacer(minLength: 25)
            }
        }
        .id(msg.id)
        //.padding(msg.myMsg ? .leading : .trailing, 55)
        //.padding(.vertical,10)
    }
}

// Bubble Arrow...

struct BubbleArrow : Shape {
    
    var myMsg : Bool
    
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: myMsg ? [.topLeft, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight] : [.topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
        
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}


// Custom Rounded Shape...
/*
struct RoundedShape : Shape {
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize())
        
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}*/

// Model Data For Message...

struct Message : Identifiable, Equatable {
    
    var id: Date
    var message: String
    var myMsg: Bool
    //var profilePic: String
    //var photo: Data?
    
}

class Messages: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var messages : [Message] = []
    
    //sample data...
    
    init() {
        let strings = ["Hi!", "hello!", "How are you doing?!", "Fine, I just want to talk about life", "ok, I may be able to help with that", "This is awesome, thanks", "So what do you want to talk about?", "movies sound like a good topic. Let's start there!", "Ok, so tell me: What's you favorite movie?", "Definitely, interstellar for sure."]
         
        for i in 0..<strings.count{
            
            //simple logic for two sided message View...
            
            messages.append(Message(id: Date(), message: strings[i], myMsg: i % 2 == 0 ? false : true))
        }
    }
    
    func writeMessage(id: Date, msg: String, photo: Data?, myMsg: Bool){
        
        messages.append((Message(id: id, message: msg, myMsg: myMsg)))
        
        
    }
}
```

```swift
//keyboard.swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

final class KeyboardHandler: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    private let keyboardWillShow = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
        .compactMap { ($0.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)?.height }
    
    private let keyboardWillHide = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
        .map {_ in CGFloat.zero }
    
    init() {
        cancellable = Publishers.Merge(keyboardWillShow, keyboardWillHide)
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: \.self.keyboardHeight, on: self)
    }
}
```

Here is the link to Home file in swift -> [ios home code snippet](https://gist.github.com/jeff-ridgeway/1104f9b8a4d9af1ea528f89494e363d4)

Any help would be appreciated on this end in terms of the UI!